# How do I remove a screen capture recorder that is being detected by Chrome as a webcam?

Tags: google-chrome, camera, webcam, screen-recording

The problem first occurred when both Chrome and Firefox were not detecting my HP HD webcam while writing an  exam on AMCAT platform. Both the browsers automatically chose screen capture recorder as my webcam, and I was not allowed to manually change this selection. I later uninstalled OBS Studio and several other video recording and editing softwares, but chrome detects a screen capture recorder as a webcam. I uninstalled and reinstalled chrome, but to no avail. I want chrome to detect only my builtin HP HD webcam.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj0y8.png)